# Why does 'Net::HTTPUnknownResponse.kind_of? Net::HTTPResponse' return 'false'?

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am using library `net/http`, and am trying to check if a response is type `Net::HTTPResponse`. I tried:

```
Net::HTTPUnknownResponse.kind_of? Net::HTTPResponse
# => false
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. What's wrong? You tell us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kind_of?` is used to check whether an object is an *instance* of a given class, e.g.

```
1.kind_of? Numeric
#=> true
```

You can't just replace the instance with its class:

```
Integer.kind_of? Numeric
#=> false
```

Because `Integer` (the class) is an instance of `Class`:

```
Integer.kind_of? Class
#=> true
```

Instead you can use [`<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-3C) to check whether the receiver is a subclass of a given class (or module, it's not limited to classes):

```
Integer < Numeric
#=> true

Integer < Comparable
#=> true
```

In your specific case:

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTPUnknownResponse < Net::HTTPResponse
#=> true
```

Note that the above code will *always* return `true` (unless you change the class hierarchy). If you are using the `net/http` library, your response object should be an *instance* of `Net::HTTPUnknownResponse`, not the class itself.